# R: a quais objetos o atributo names() se aplica?

Tags: r

Estou um pouco confuso com o papel do atributo `names()` em diferentes objetos.

Além do uso normal, em data.frames, vejo nos exemplos do `help(names)` que também podem ser usados para vetores (tanto numéricos como string) e listas. Mas para matrizes `names(M)` retorna `NULL`. Veja estes exemplos:

```
# vetor numérico
names(islands)
islands

#vertor textual
a <- c("a","b")
names(a) <- c("Na","Nb")
a

#listas
z <- list(a = 1, b = "c", c = 1:3)
names(z)

#data.frames
x <-  data.frame(V1=c(1,2,3),V2=c(3,2,1))
names(x)
x

#matrizes:
y <- as.matrix(x)
names(y)
y
```

Factors também podem ter nomes?
Porque só matrizes não tem "names"? 
`colnames()` e `rownames()` são atributos diferentes de `names()`?

Answer (score 3):

Matrizes podem ter `names` também. Quase tudo pode ter `names` no `R`. A forma mais simples de pensar nestas questões é a seguinte: o `names` se refere ao nome do **elemento** do objeto. E `rownames` e `colnames` são nomes das **dimensões** do objeto.

## Vetores, matrizes e arrays

Por exemplo, em um vetor, o `names` atribui um nome a *cada elemento* do vetor.

```
x <- 1:10
names(x) <- paste0("elemento", 1:10)
x
 elemento1  elemento2  elemento3  elemento4  elemento5  elemento6  elemento7  elemento8 
         1          2          3          4          5          6          7          8 
 elemento9 elemento10 
         9         10
```

E agora você pode usar o nome para selecionar o elemento:

```
x["elemento1"]
elemento1 
        1
```

Uma matriz (ou um array) nada mais é do que um vetor com mais um atributo: *dimensões*. Vamos transformar o vetor `x` acima em uma matriz 2 x 5. Agora você pode nomear todos os elementos da matriz com names, bem como nomear as dimensões, isto é, linhas e colunas, utilizando `rownames` e `colnames` respectivamente:

```
dim(x) <- c(2, 5)
names(x) <- paste0("elemento", 1:10)
rownames(x) <- paste0("linha", 1:2)
colnames(x) <- paste0("coluna", 1:5)
x
       coluna1 coluna2 coluna3 coluna4 coluna5
linha1       1       3       5       7       9
linha2       2       4       6       8      10
attr(,"names")
 [1] "elemento1"  "elemento2"  "elemento3"  "elemento4"  "elemento5"  "elemento6" 
 [7] "elemento7"  "elemento8"  "elemento9"  "elemento10"
```

Veja que agora você pode fazer subset com os nomes tanto dos elementos quanto das dimensões:

```
x["elemento10"]
elemento10 
        10 
x[,"coluna5"]
linha1 linha2 
     9     10
```

Matrizes têm somente duas dimensões. Para mais de duas dimensões temos o array. Vamos transformas a matriz anterior em um array 2 X 5 x 1. Com o array você pode continuar utilizando `rownames` e `colnames` para nomear a primeira e a segunda dimensão. Para nomear a terceira dimensão, você vai utilizar `dimnames`:

```
dim(x) <- c(2, 5, 1)
names(x) <- paste0("elemento", 1:10)
rownames(x) <- paste0("linha", 1:2)
colnames(x) <- paste0("coluna", 1:5)
dimnames(x)[[3]] <- "terceira dimensão"
x
, , terceira dimensão

       coluna1 coluna2 coluna3 coluna4 coluna5
linha1       1       3       5       7       9
linha2       2       4       6       8      10

attr(,"names")
 [1] "elemento1"  "elemento2"  "elemento3"  "elemento4"  "elemento5"  "elemento6"  "elemento7"  "elemento8" 
 [9] "elemento9"  "elemento10"
```

O `dimanames` é a função primitiva para dimensões. Então obviamente você poderia nomear tanto as linhas e colunas também com `dimnames`.

```
# Nomeando linhas e colunas usando dimnames
dimnames(x)[[1]] <- paste0("linha", 1:2)
dimnames(x)[[2]] <- paste0("coluna", 1:5)
```

## Listas e data.frames

Se você criar a lista `z <- list(a = 1, b = "c", c = 1:3)`, note que os elementos dela tem os nomes `a`, `b` e `c`, e é isso que o names retorna.

```
names(z)
[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

O data.frame é uma lista também, com um atributo `row.names` e com a restrição de que todos os elementos têm de ter o mesmo tamanho. Vamos transformar `z` em um data.frame:

```
z <- as.data.frame(z)
  a b c
1 1 c 1
2 1 c 2
3 1 c 3
```

Agora fica claro porque no `data.frame` o `names` é igual ao `colnames`. Isso ocorre porque o data.frame nada mais é do que uma lista e as colunas são os elementos da lista.

Por fim, fatores são vetores, e podem ter `names` normalmente.

Answer (score 2):

A sua pergunta está relacionada a estruturas de dados.

Veja o livro do Hadley: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html

`names` é um tipo de atributo (que são os metadados no R), que serve para dar nomes a elementos de um vetor. Assim, você pode atribuir nomes usando `names`, tanto para vetores atômicos (construídos geralmente com `c()`) quanto para listas (construídos geralmente com `list()`). Assim, um objeto com classe `data.frame` é uma lista, que por sua vez é um vetor, então pode receber o atributo `names`.

Matrizes, no entanto, são um caso especial de arrays. Um array (constuído geralmente com `array()`) é um vetor que possui o atributo `dim`.

Assim, é possível atribuir nomes a um `array` ou `matrix`, mas isso significa atribuir um nome a cada elemento, e não às colunas ou linhas. Por exemplo:

```
x <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6), nrow=2)
attributes(x)
names(x) <- c('a', 'b', 'c') # atribui nomes aos três primeiros elementos do array
attributes(x)
colnames(x) <- c('a', 'b', 'c') # atribui nomes das colunas do array (dimensão 2)
attributes(x)

dim(x) <- NULL # transforma a matriz em vetor atômico (os nomes são dropados)
names(x) <- c('a', 'b', 'c') # atribui nomes aos três primeiros elementos do vetor
attributes(x)
```

Apesar de ser possível atribuir `names` a cada um dos elementos de um `array`, isso pode não ser útil, e por isso que existem as generalizações `rownames` e `colnames`.

Acho que agora dá para responder suas perguntas.

- Um `factor` é um vetor de números inteiros com os atributos `class` e `levels`. Logo, como é um vetor, pode ter nomes sim. Veja por exemplo `x <- factor(c(a='A',b='B',c='C'))`
- Matrizes não nascem com `names` provavelmente porquê é inútil nomear cada elemento do vetor. Pode notar que a criação de uma matriz a partir de um vetor nomeado, por exemplo: `matrix(c(a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4,e=5,f=5), nrow=2)` joga fora o atributo `names`. No entanto, matrizes podem receber `names` sim.
- `colnames` e `rownames` são de fato atributos diferentes de `names`, e fazem parte da lista `dimnames`.